# getting role from the user logged in returns no data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to get the role of the user which just logged in the website. 
I am doing this:

```
string userRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(LoginUser.UserName).ToString();
```

but that returns 'System.String', not the real role :(.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

P.S. LoginUser is the login control

Comment: GetRolesForUser returns an array of strings (string[]) *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx*

Comment: It actually returns an array and when you call `.ToString()` on that array it returns the type name and it must return `System.String[]`

Comment: In general, calling `.ToString()` to obtain *data* (rather than display text) should be a warning sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] roles = RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(LoginUser.UserName);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx

Comment: After that, you can get the role with `roles[0]`.